# Why do many projects that use GCC only compile at -O2?

Tags: gcc, optimization

I've noticed that, when calling `make` on a large number of free software projects that are built with GCC, that they only use the `-O2` optimization option, even though `-O3` does more optimizations. Why is that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Optimization in GCC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368746/optimization-in-gcc)